# Cloning a method in c#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class A:

```
class A
{
    void b() {...}
}
```

and a class B:

```
class B
{
    A m;
}
```

This way, if I write `B x`, I can call `x.m.b()`.

What I need is to dynamically create a method `b()` inside the B class, so I could use it as `x.b()` (of course, the results from calls `x.m.b()` and `x.b()` should be the same).

How can I do it?

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to do this?

Comment: No, why are you _trying_ to do this, because you can't actually _do_ this. Why do you need to rewrite the C# language?

Comment: @Cyral was trying to make the decorator pattern inherit the behavior of the internal class without copying the method or calling it using the decorated class.

Comment: Is there a real-world case where this would be used or is this question purely academic?

Comment: @Yuck Both. I was/am trying to actually use it, but even if there is a better solution I'm still interested to know if this can be done.

Comment: Containment is _not_ inheritance. `A` is contained in `B` so access rules apply. If this was for `struct` it would be a legitimate question, but with classes you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Yuck this is quite common issue with trying to unit-test code that is not designed to be testable - intercepting non-virtual method is tricky... But for new code that one writes I see no reason of doing so with classes/structs. Easy to achieve with interfaces - most DI containers use that, some like Unity (see [Interception using Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)) even allow to create standalone interface wrappers outside container.

Comment: Have you read this article?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx

Comment: What makes this different than a wrapper method? The "dynamically create" part?

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp

Comment: @Warlock Well, i watched it through. 
Ill try to explain the question using that example. If the NameCardDecorator would have a GetDiscountRate() method and we crated a base, decorated it with NameCardDecorator and then with a CherryDecorator, getting an object (lets call it w) of BakeryComponent class, we wouldnt be able to use w.GetDiscountRate() since its hidden under the m_BaseComponent field.

Comment: You cannot decorate a method if it's not presented in the base Decorator class. If this is out of the scope of the decorator you need an additional decorator for this special functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one generic solution (where you won't have to f.e create delegates for every method from `A` you want). Unfortunately, It won't be a strongly-typed one. If you want so, please see other answers.

```
class A
{
    public int B()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly A m = new A();

    private static readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<MethodInfo>> AMethods =
        new Lazy<IEnumerable<MethodInfo>>(() =>
                                          {
                                              var type = typeof (A);
                                              return type.GetMethods(
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                  BindingFlags.Public);
                                          });

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(
                           InvokeMemberBinder binder, 
                           object[] args, 
                           out object result)
    {
        if (base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result))
        {
            return true;
        }

        var methods = AMethods.Value;

        var method = methods.SingleOrDefault(mth => mth.Name == binder.Name); 
            // TODO: additional match (arguments type to handle overloads)
        if (method == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        result = method.Invoke(this.m, args);

        return true;
    }

    public int OtherBMethods()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var b = new B();  
int result = ((dynamic)b).B();    
int other = b.OtherBMethods();
```

or

```
dynamic b = new B();
int result = b.B();
int other = b.OtherBMethods();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
By the way, why do we need 'lazy' when were getting the methods list?

Comment: @h8red see, that `AMethods` is static. The purpose of it to cache all available `A` methods in order to improve perfromance. `Lazy` class is used for handle multi-thread access (without this, when two threads would access that variable as saw that it's null, they could both create new instance). Please reffer great Jon Skeet's blog: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: In this case, also static constructor could be used, but `Lazy` is more convinient to me :)

Comment: Thanks once again.
Just one last thing (if its not hard for you to answer). What should i do if i would like to add an event handler to any event from a class?

Comment: Then you need to override `TryGetmember` to the similar as `TryInvokeMember`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this  with delegates, in modern C# this could look like this

```
public class A
{
    public void b() {...}
}

public class B
{
    private A m = new A();
    public Action b = ()=>m.b();
}

public void Main()
{
     new B().b(); // This now invokes your delegates that invokes the b method on it's internal m object
}
```

Could also just do it with classical methods and simply expose a b method that does the exact same thing, don't see anything special / hard here? If you're trying to accomplish something else you need to clarify your question, like if you want to automate this there are easy compile time (T4 text templates) or at runtime (generating dynamic proxies).

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to do is implement Decorator pattern in C#.

> GoF defines Decorator pattern as "Attach additional responsibilities
>   to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to
>   subclassing for extending functionality.

I would like to recommend look throught this article ["Understanding and Implementing Decorator Pattern in C#"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp).

I have created a simple example of the Decorator pattern implementation when you decorate  `Concrete` with `A` and `B` functionality.

```
interface IDecorator
{
    void Print();
}

class Concrete : IDecorator
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-> Concrete");
    }
}

class A : IDecorator
{
    IDecorator decorator;
    public A(IDecorator decorator)
    {
        this.decorator = decorator;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        decorator.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("-> A");
    }
}

class B : IDecorator
{
    IDecorator decorator;
    public B(IDecorator decorator)
    {
        this.decorator = decorator;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        decorator.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("-> B");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("concrete object that should be decorated");
        var concrete = new Concrete();
        concrete.Print();

        Console.WriteLine("let's decorate this object with A decorator");
        var decoratedWithA = new A(concrete);
        decoratedWithA.Print();

        Console.WriteLine("let's decorate this object with B decorator");
        var decoratedWithB = new B(concrete);
        decoratedWithB.Print();

        Console.WriteLine("let's decorate concrete with A and B");
        var decoratedWithAB = new B(new A(concrete));
        decoratedWithAB.Print();
    }
}
```

> I have an abstract A class and classes A1 : A, A2 : A, A3 : A. Then i
>   also have a method named c(). I want to create classes
>   A1_with_c_method, A2_with_c_method, A3_with_c_methos while leaving A1,
>   A2 and A3 unharmed. What is the best way to do this? –  h8red

You could do something like this:

```
abstract class A
{
}

class A1 : A
{
}

class A2 : A
{
}

class A3 : A
{
}

#region Not a good idea, because too many classes

class A1_with_c : A1
{
    public void c() { }
}

class A2_with_c : A2
{
    public void c() { }
}

class A3_with_c : A3
{
    public void c() { }
}

#endregion


// Decorate A with the c() method
class BaseDecorator
{
    public A Instance { get; private set; }
    public BaseDecorator(A instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
    }

    public virtual void c()
    {
        // do something with instance
    }
}

class Decorator : BaseDecorator
{
    BaseDecorator decorator;
    public Decorator(BaseDecorator decorator)
        : base(decorator.Instance)
    {
        this.decorator = decorator;
    }
    public override void c()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ok");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // not good
        new A1_with_c().c();
        new A2_with_c().c();
        new A3_with_c().c();

        // better
        var a_with_c = new BaseDecorator(new A1());
        a_with_c.c();

        // Let's decorate with something interesting
        new Decorator(a_with_c).c();
    }
}
```

Comment: And how is it going to look if both A and B would add new methods?

Comment: They doesn't add new methods, they extend (decorate) existing functionality.

Comment: And what should i do if i need to add new methods? Is the decorator pattern still working here?
The whole things looks like this.
I have an abstract A class and classes A1 : A, A2 : A, A3 : A.
Then i also have a method named c(). 
I want to create classes A1_with_c_method, A2_with_c_method, A3_with_c_methos while leaving A1, A2 and A3 unharmed. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that this really seems odd and I'm wondering why you would ever want to do this but here is a possibility for you.

```
interface IHasMethodb
{
    void b();
}

class A : IHasMethodb
{
    public void b() { ... }
}

class B : IHasMethodb
{
    A m;
    public void b() { return m.b(); }
}
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you either want the concept of wrapping a method, which in your example is as simple as:

```
class A {
   public void b() { ... }
}

class B {
   A m;
   public void b() { m.b(); }
}
```

Allowing you to:

```
B x = new B();
x.b();
```

If you want to be able to "dynamically create" the method then this might be more applicable, using an `Action<T>` to allow you to do whatever you like with the `A` instance, without actually exposing it:

```
class A {
   public void b() {...}
}

class B {
   A m;
   public Action<A> doSomethingWithA;

   public void b() {
      if (doSomethingWithA != null)
         doSomethingWithA(m);
   }
}
```

Then you can:

```
B x = new B();
x.doSomethingWithA = a => a.b();
x.b();
```